# Insert Maximum Amount of rows into another table query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have three tables. 
I need to insert the near maximum amount of persons into the person training table. The person training table has the maximum  persons required.

So for instance I have 30 Persons and the required amount is like 27 , 27 persons should be inserted into the person training table

Likewise if the amount of persons needed is like 15 and 15 already allocated, I don't need anything to be inserted.

Can this be accomplished

```
Person
Pk personId
firstName
lastName

Person_Training
PK FK personId
PK FK trainingId
signed   

Training
T trainingId
Location
personsNeeded
date
```

I have tried this but to no avail

```
INSERT INTO Person_Training(personId,trainingId)
SELECT personId , trainingId
  FROM Person , Training
 WHERE Training.date = '9-10-2013'
Having COUNT(Person.personId) < Training.personsNeeded
```

Comment: Person.personsNeeded is incorrect. personsNeeded column is in the Training table. It should be Training.personsNeeded

Comment: yes it was a typo, but it still doesn't work

Comment: [Do not use `HAVING` for items that should be in the `WHERE` clause.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: Ok, but I can't COUNT in the where or select. What should I do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you are missing is the joining of all of the tables.

```
from Person 
inner join person_Training on person_Training.personID = Person.PersonID
inner join Training on Training.trainingID = Person_Training.trainingID
```

Don't forget the group by clause on all selected fields.  The group by goes before the Having clause

```
Group by Person.personID, Training.trainingID
```